# How to delete (non-favorites) audio files that are stored in internal memory in Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, mediastore

I have hundreds of songs on the phone and I would like just delete non-favorite songs. Is it possible by code? Using the Android's default music player?

Answer (score 0):

try this code and please put file path then run

```
File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```